# Why does ROS keep eating disk space even though I clean its log frequently?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am running ROS (kinect) on ubuntu 16.04, and I clean the ROS log using roslog clean command every 10 minutes.
However, when I check the disk usage using df command, it shows my disk usage keeps increasing over time. After 2 hours, 10 Gb is gone. I am sure it's not the roslog because I cleaned it very often and it never exceeds 200MB. However, when I close ROS, the disk space is back immediately.

But for some reason, I can't close ROS.

It's driving me crazy and I can't figure this out after days of investigation. Please HELP!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284818/why-does-ros-keep-eating-disk-space-even-though-i-clean-its-log-frequently?/) by [zwz](https://answers.ros.org/users/34055/zwz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your log files might not be actually removed since "rm" only does an unlink. The file gets removed when no process has opened the files, see e.g. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted)

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0